# .htaccess rewrite not doing anything

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a page with the URL of `http://www.freshmarketstores.com/departments/produce/recipe.php?ing=Akane_Apples&recipe=59` that I would like to be cleaned up to look like `http://www.freshmarketstores.com/departments/produce/recipe/Akane_Apples/59`

Right now, in my .htaccess file that is located in the produce folder, I have the following code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^recipe/(.*)/(.*)$ recipe.php?ing=$1&recipe=$2 [L]
```

Currently, this does not affect anything. when the `recipe.php?ing=Akane_Apples$recipe=59` url is loaded, it loads fine, but does not do the rewrite. This is my first attempt at URL rewriting and can't figure this thing out.

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT:**
Okay, so after some learning last night, I realize I was approaching this backwards. I am able to type in http://www.freshmarketstores.com/departments/produce/recipe/Akane_Apples/59 and get the resource that is stored at .../produce/recipe.php?ing=Akane_Apples&recipe=59. Thanks for all of your help on that.

My question now, is can you go the opposite way? If I type in .../produce/recipe.php?ing=Akane_Apples&recipe=59, how can I get it to redirect to the /produce/recipe/Akane_Apples/59?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure you have the

```
AccessFileName .htaccess
```

setup in your Server and virtual host configuration files in apache, the default is setup to be .htaccess however it is not restricted to only that and can be named anything.

default config file for a debian based system is `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and for most other systems `httpd.conf` in the apache install directory

once the access file is setup and you have mod_rewrite enabled you can do something as below

http://www.freshmarketstores.com/departments/produce/Akane_Apples/59

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^recipe/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /recipe.php?ing=$1&recipe=$2 [L]
```

Comment: How is this affected if I am on Bluehost. I don't believe I have access to the httpd.conf file. I also know that the .htaccess file itself is working, because I did a test of:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test\.html$ test.php [L]

to redirect the test.html to test.php, which worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but this is still not working. Just so you know that the mod_rewrite is working, I have changed the .htaccess file to rewrite the following link http://www.freshmarketstores.com/departments/produce/test.html (which should just display the words "this is the html page") to http://www.freshmarketstores.com/departments/produce/test.php, which displays "this is the php page". So I know Rewrite is working, but it is as if the Regex part of the recipe statement isn't matching

Comment: Do any of the examples work? mine or another post?
maybe you need to follow a tutorial to get it working [link](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/server/apache/mod-rewrite/) which will also give you a **better** and **deeper** understanding of htaccess

Comment: None of the examples are working, and I started this whole process with a tutorial. I totally agree I need a better and deeper understanding of all this. I am looking at your link now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# internal forwarding to /recipe.php
RewriteRule ^recipe/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ recipe.php?ing=$1&recipe=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

# external redirect to /recipe
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+recipe\.php\?ing=([^&]+)&recipe=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ recipe/%1/%2? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, but this isn't working. It is still just loading normally.

Comment: Are .htaccess & mod_rewrite enabled? What is your URI that you're testing with?

Comment: I am extremely new to all of this .htaccess and mod_rewrite stuff, but I would say that they are definitely enabled (I would say this because if you visit http://www.freshmarketstores.com/departments/produce/test.html it does a re-write to http://www.freshmarketstores.com/departments/produce/test.php [as evidenced by the type on the page displaying "this is the php page"]). I am on a shared hosting plan on Bluehost, so I know that mod_rewrite is enabled (and I have no access to .httpd.conf file). What else should I be looking at?

Comment: To test .htaccess you can put some garbage text on top and see if that generates 500 error or not.

Comment: Yes, I get a 500 error when I put garbage text at the top of the .htacess file.

Comment: Its really late here, so I need to sign off now. But what I can suggest you to please check your Apache's access.log and error.log files. Just fyi that `http://www.freshmarketstores.com/departments/produce/test.html` showing PHP output is possible without enabling mod_rewrite as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should be okay with

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?ing=([^&]+)&recipe=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(departments/produce/recipe)\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/%1/%2 [NC,R=301,L]
```